# How to get one to many association in nested array when using Sequelize raw query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT "branchManagement"."id",
    "branchManagement"."branch_unique_id" AS "branchUniqueId",
    "branchManagement"."name",
    "branchManagement"."branch_head" AS "branchHead",
    "branchManagement"."mobile_number" AS "mobileNumber",
    "branchManagement"."email_id" AS "emailId",
    "branchManagement"."address",
    "branchManagement"."state_id" AS "stateId",
    "branchManagement"."city_id" AS "cityId",
    "branchManagement"."pin_code" AS "pinCode",
    "branchManagement"."created_by" AS "createdBy",
    "branchManagement"."modified_by" AS "modifiedBy",
    "branchManagement"."is_active" AS "isActive",
    "branchManagement"."createdAt",
    "branchManagement"."updatedAt",
    "state"."id" AS "state.id",
    "state"."name" AS "state.name",
    "city"."id" AS "city.id",
    "city"."name" AS "city.name",
    "assignedPincode"."id" AS "assignedPincode.id",
    "assignedPincode"."branchManagementId" AS "assignedPincode.branchManagementId",
    "assignedPincode"."pinCode" AS "assignedPincode.pinCode", "assignedPincode"."isActive" AS "assignedPincode.isActive",
    "assignedPincode"."createdAt" AS "assignedPincode.createdAt", "assignedPincode"."updatedAt" AS "assignedPincode.updatedAt"
    FROM "branch_management" AS "branchManagement"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "state" AS "state" ON "branchManagement"."state_id" = "state"."id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "city" AS "city" ON "branchManagement"."city_id" = "city"."id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "branchPincode" AS "assignedPincode" ON "branchManagement"."id" = "assignedPincode"."branchManagementId" AND "assignedPincode"."isActive" = true
    WHERE (("branchManagement"."name" ILIKE '%' OR CAST("branchManagement"."id" AS VARCHAR) ILIKE '%' OR
    "branchManagement"."branch_unique_id" ILIKE '%' OR "branchManagement"."branch_head" ILIKE '%' OR
    CAST("mobile_number" AS VARCHAR) ILIKE '%'))
    AND "branchManagement"."is_active" = true
```

expecting array of assignedPincode inside each branch but getting different record for each assignedPincode is there any way to use Sequelize eager loading in raw query

have tried raw:true and nest:true but getting expected output

Answer (score 1):

If you need grouped associated model records you shouldn't use `raw` option because you will simply get a result similar to a result from `sequelize.query`.

If you simply don't need model instances you can convert them to plain objects (including nested associations) like this:

```js
const models = await Model.findAll({})
const plainObjects = models.map(x => x.get({ plain: true })
```

Comment: I am using raw query because of pagination problem
using above query getting output as

`[{
   branchId: 1,
   assignedPincode: { id: 1 }
},
{
   branchId: 1,
   assignedPincode: { id: 2 }
}]`

want output as 

`[{
   branchId: 1,
   assignedPincode: [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 }]
}]`

is there any way to do it sequelize when using raw query

Comment: Raw query does not group child associated records at all